# parsing an xml data in blackberry as specified formate

Tags: blackberry

This is one file which is stored in my res folder. I want to parse this data.

```
<ROOT> 
<ROW Name="Product Name~B" CheckBox="" Type="PerformanceNormal"
Count="1" ChildCount="1" Show="Y" Refine="B"> 
   <COL Page="0" Image="" ProductID=""/> 
   <COL Page="1" Image="" ProductID="3">Sainsbury's aromatherapy citrus mint</COL> 
   <COL Page="1" Image="" ProductID="4">TestPerf</COL> 
   <COL Page="1" Image="" ProductID="5">TestPerf001</COL> 
   <COL Page="1" Image="" ProductID="24">Ashraf Product</COL> 
   <COL Page="2" Image="" ProductID="25">Acb</COL> 
</ROW> 
<ROW Name="Region~H" CheckBox="" Type="PerformanceNormal" Count="2" 
ChildCount="1" Show="Y" Refine="H"> 
   <COL Page="0" Image="" ProductID=""/> 
   <COL Page="1" Image="" ProductID="3">Western Europe</COL> 
   <COL Page="1" Image="" ProductID="4">Western Europe</COL> 
   <COL Page="1" Image="" ProductID="5">Western Europe</COL> 
   <COL Page="1" Image="" ProductID="24">Central and Eastern Europe</COL> 
   <COL Page="2" Image="" ProductID="25">Central and Eastern Europe</COL> 
</ROW> 
<ROW Name="Country~H" CheckBox="" Type="PerformanceNormal" 
Count="3" ChildCount="1" Show="Y" Refine="H"> 
   <COL Page="0" Image="" ProductID=""/> 
   <COL Page="1" Image="" ProductID="3">United Kingdom</COL> 
   <COL Page="1" Image="" ProductID="4">Belgium</COL> 
   <COL Page="1" Image="" ProductID="5">Belgium</COL> 
   <COL Page="1" Image="" ProductID="24">Czech Republic</COL> 
   <COL Page="2" Image="" ProductID="25">Czech Republic</COL> 
</ROW> 
</ROOT>
```

I want tp parse all data name, checkbox,type this is row information

and inside ROW tag multiple COL tags are there i want get data from COL also following data
page,image,productID

through all data i want to make a table on the screen

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note:If it is not useful then please ignore this.

I found myself to answer my question following way we can separate out (print)all details
we can do it using to parser 
1)DOM parser
2)SAX parser

```
public void ReadAndPrintXMLfileUsingDOM()
    {

        try {
              DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
              DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
              InputStream rStream = null;
                try
                {
                    rStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("sample.xml");;
                }catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                Document doc = docBuilder.parse(rStream);
                doc.getDocumentElement ().normalize ();
                System.out.println ("Root element of the doc is " + 
                doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
                NodeList listOfPersons = doc.getElementsByTagName("ROW");
                int totalPersons = listOfPersons.getLength();
                System.out.println("Total no of people : " + totalPersons);
                for(int s=0; s<listOfPersons.getLength() ; s++)
                {
                    Node firstPersonNode = listOfPersons.item(s);
                    Element firstPersonElement = (Element)firstPersonNode;
                    System.out.println( "==============Name value = " + firstPersonElement.getAttribute( "Name" ) );
                    System.out.println( "===============CheckBox value = " + firstPersonElement.getAttribute( "CheckBox" ));
                    System.out.println( "==============Type value = " + firstPersonElement.getAttribute( "Type" ));
                    System.out.println( "==============Count value = " + firstPersonElement.getAttribute( "Count" ));
                    System.out.println( "==============ChildCount value = " + firstPersonElement.getAttribute( "ChildCount" ));
                    System.out.println( "==============Show value = " + firstPersonElement.getAttribute( "Show" ));
                    System.out.println( "==============Refine value = " + firstPersonElement.getAttribute( "Refine" ));
                    NodeList firstNameList = firstPersonElement.getElementsByTagName("COL");

                    int child_lng=firstNameList.getLength();
                    for(int j=0;j<child_lng;j++)
                    {
                          Node innernode=firstNameList.item(j);
                          Element firstPersonElement1 = (Element)innernode;
                          NamedNodeMap attributes = innernode.getAttributes();
                            Node value=firstNameList.item(j).getChildNodes().item(0); 
                          System.out.println( "==============Page value = " + firstPersonElement1.getAttribute( "Page" ) );
                          System.out.println( "==============Image value = " + firstPersonElement1.getAttribute( "Image" ) );
                          System.out.println( "==============ProductID value = " + firstPersonElement1.getAttribute( "ProductID" ) );
                          System.out.println("+++++++++++++++Node Value : " +value.getNodeValue());

                    }
                 }
          }catch (SAXParseException err) 
          {
              System.out.println ("** Parsing error" + ", line " 
               + err.getLineNumber () + ", uri " + err.getSystemId ());
              System.out.println(" " + err.getMessage ());
          }catch (SAXException e) 
          {
              Exception x = e.getException ();
              ((x == null) ? e : x).printStackTrace ();
          }catch (Exception t) 
          {
              System.out.println(t.getMessage());
          }
    }
```

second method is

```
public void ReadAndWriteXMLFileUsingSAXParser(){

        try
        {
            DefaultHandler handler = new MyHandler();
//              parseXmlFile("infilename.xml", handler, true);
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
            InputStream rStream = null;
            rStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("sample.xml");
            saxParser.parse(rStream, handler);
        }catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    String rootname;Attributes atr;
    private boolean flag=false;
    public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName,
                             String qName, Attributes atts)  {
     rootname=localName;
     atr=atts;
     if(rootname.equalsIgnoreCase("ROW")){
         flag=true;
         int length = atts.getLength();
         for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
             String name = atts.getQName(i);
             String value = atts.getValue(i);
             System.out.println(name+"**********"+value);
         } 
     }


    }
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length){
        String value=new String(ch,start,length);
        if(flag)
        {
            if(rootname.equalsIgnoreCase("COL")){
                 int length2 = atr.getLength();
                 for (int i=0; i<length2; i++) {
                     String name1 = atr.getQName(i);
                     String value1 = atr.getValue(i);
                     System.out.println(name1+"**********"+value1);
                 } 
                System.out.println("++++++++++++++"+value);
            }
        }

    }
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName){
        rootname=localName;
         if(rootname.equalsIgnoreCase("ROW")){
             flag=false;
         }
    }
}
```

we got output as when DOM parser

```
Root element of the doc is ROOT
Total no of people : 3
==============Name value = Product Name~B
===============CheckBox value = 
==============Type value = PerformanceNormal
==============Count value = 1
==============ChildCount value = 1
==============Show value = Y
==============Refine value = B
==============Page value = 1
==============Image value = 
==============ProductID value = 3
+++++++++++++++Node Value : Sainsbury's aromatherapy citrus mint
==============Page value = 1
==============Image value = 
==============ProductID value = 4
+++++++++++++++Node Value : TestPerf
==============Page value = 1
==============Image value = 
==============ProductID value = 5
+++++++++++++++Node Value : TestPerf001
==============Page value = 1
==============Image value = 
==============ProductID value = 24
+++++++++++++++Node Value : Ashraf Product
==============Page value = 2
==============Image value = 
==============ProductID value = 25
+++++++++++++++Node Value : Acb
==============Name value = Region~H
===============CheckBox value = 
==============Type value = PerformanceNormal
==============Count value = 2
==============ChildCount value = 1
==============Show value = Y
==============Refine value = H
==============Page value = 1
==============Image value = 
==============ProductID value = 3
+++++++++++++++Node Value : Western Europe
==============Page value = 1
==============Image value = 
==============ProductID value = 4
+++++++++++++++Node Value : Western Europe
==============Page value = 1
==============Image value = 
==============ProductID value = 5
+++++++++++++++Node Value : Western Europe
==============Page value = 1
==============Image value = 
==============ProductID value = 24
+++++++++++++++Node Value : Central and Eastern Europe
==============Page value = 2
==============Image value = 
==============ProductID value = 25
+++++++++++++++Node Value : Central and Eastern Europe
==============Name value = Country~H
===============CheckBox value = 
==============Type value = PerformanceNormal
==============Count value = 3
==============ChildCount value = 1
==============Show value = Y
==============Refine value = H
==============Page value = 1
==============Image value = 
==============ProductID value = 3
+++++++++++++++Node Value : United Kingdom
==============Page value = 1
==============Image value = 
==============ProductID value = 4
+++++++++++++++Node Value : Belgium
==============Page value = 1
==============Image value = 
==============ProductID value = 5
+++++++++++++++Node Value : Belgium
==============Page value = 1
==============Image value = 
==============ProductID value = 24
+++++++++++++++Node Value : Czech Republic
==============Page value = 2
==============Image value = 
==============ProductID value = 25
+++++++++++++++Node Value : Czech Republic
```

out as when SAXParsing

```
Name**********Product Name~B
CheckBox**********
Type**********PerformanceNormal
Count**********1
ChildCount**********1
Show**********Y
Refine**********B
Page**********1
Image**********
ProductID**********3
++++++++++++++Sainsbury's aromatherapy citrus mint
Page**********1
Image**********
ProductID**********4
++++++++++++++TestPerf
Page**********1
Image**********
ProductID**********5
++++++++++++++TestPerf001
Page**********1
Image**********
ProductID**********24
++++++++++++++Ashraf Product
Page**********2
Image**********
ProductID**********25
++++++++++++++Acb
Name**********Region~H
CheckBox**********
Type**********PerformanceNormal
Count**********2
ChildCount**********1
Show**********Y
Refine**********H
Page**********1
Image**********
ProductID**********3
++++++++++++++Western Europe
Page**********1
Image**********
ProductID**********4
++++++++++++++Western Europe
Page**********1
Image**********
ProductID**********5
++++++++++++++Western Europe
Page**********1
Image**********
ProductID**********24
++++++++++++++Central and Eastern Europe
Page**********2
Image**********
ProductID**********25
++++++++++++++Central and Eastern Europe
Name**********Country~H
CheckBox**********
Type**********PerformanceNormal
Count**********3
ChildCount**********1
Show**********Y
Refine**********H
Page**********1
Image**********
ProductID**********3
++++++++++++++United Kingdom
Page**********1
Image**********
ProductID**********4
++++++++++++++Belgium
Page**********1
Image**********
ProductID**********5
++++++++++++++Belgium
Page**********1
Image**********
ProductID**********24
++++++++++++++Czech Republic
Page**********2
Image**********
ProductID**********25
++++++++++++++Czech Republic
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void getFeedObjects(InputStream is)  throws ParserConfigurationException 
{
    xmlNewsFeedHandler = new NewsFeedHandler();
    try 
    {
        SAXParser parser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
        parser.parse(is, xmlNewsFeedHandler);
    }
    catch (ParserConfigurationException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (SAXException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In `getFeedObjects()` method , you pass the `inputstream` which is get from your local resource or web resource.

Write `NewsFeedHandler()` class to parse the data.